# Decoration/Marker "U" in Visual Studio doesn't change to "A" after staging ("git add .") the file

Tags: visual-studio-code, addition, git-untracked

This is my first question in StackOverflow (hello!). :)

The thing is that with my IDE, Visual Studio Code, I can not change the "U" of untracked for an added file.

1. After I include a new file into my repository, the file is untracked by git (and therefore marked with a 'U').
2. Then I open the Terminal on VS Code and initiate git in the proper route with  `git init`.
3. After that, I stage it with the  `git add .` command, the marker it is supposed to change to "A"  but it is not the case.
4. Even when I commit the changes with  `git commit -am "first commit"` the file is still displayed as "U"...

What it is strange to me is that in the Terminal the changes, modifications, uploadings... are identified by git without any inconvenient, it is just in the Visual Studio User Interface that this thing happen.

Picture1: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrpU1.png)

My Attempts:

1. I have tried to reinstall VS Code but it is still having the same
   issue (I have a Mac with intel chip).
2. Tried with other repositories/projects... same issue.

Any help is well received.
Thank you for your time!.

Comment: Can you try setting [`git config core.ignoreCase true`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/2.14.6#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreignoreCase) ?

Comment: @LeGEC Thank you for the response but after trying your command, there are no changes.

Comment: I think you want the [tag:visual-studio-code] tag here. Everything is working fine in Git, it's just VSCode that is not working. (I updated your tags.)

Comment: @torek thanks for your contribution torek, I´ll follow your advice here!.

Comment: Ok. Can it be a case sensitivity issue ? If, if a terminal, you run `git show HEAD:` (the `:` after the `HEAD` will tell "show me the content of the root directory") do you see `README.md` ? or `Readme.md` ? or ...

Comment: Thanks again @LeGEC, it is not the case. After running `git show HEAD:` I get on return the all the files (in lowercase) including the `readme.md`.

Answer (score 0):

Using the **Source Control** the file can be added to the stage as well, it has the same result that running a `git add (file)` command but using VS Code user interface. See the image below.

1. Press the Source Control button.
2. Press the (+) button to stage the file.

[image]